# Why using IS in the sentence "one or more -something- IS not available"?

Tags: verb-forms, conjugations

Today while browsing I came across this sentence:

> One or more items in your order **is** not available

I thought it was wrong but after [a google search](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=one+or+more+items+in+your+order+IS+not+available&oq=one+or+more+items+in+your+order+IS+not+available&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) I'm confused .

Why is "IS" used instead of "ARE"? If it's correct, is there some rule to apply in this cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Either *is* or *are* is acceptable.](http://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/one-or-more-is-or-one-or-more-are/)

Whether to use *is* or *are* may depend on:

1 What your teacher says is correct;
2 What style guide you use says is correct;
3 What you think sounds better;
4 Whether you consider "one or more items" to be a singular unit, as in "Seventeen items is all I can afford."
5 Flip a coin.

In this context, it is easy to see *one or more items* as a singular set:

*One or more items* in your order is not available.

Some may prefer the rule of proximity, which says to use the nearest noun:

One of more *items* in your order *are* not available.

Frankly, the above grates on me, because of the strength of the word *one.* Or as the *Cambridge Guide to English Usage* remarks:

> For most writers the choice depends on whether you’re thinking of a single case or general principle. Usage commentators in the UK and the US have been inclined to say it should be plural; and the Harper–Heritage usage panel voted heavily in its favor (78%). Yet Webster’s English Usage (1989) found ample American evidence for the singular construction, and it’s just as common as the plural in British data from the BNC. **Writers using the singular take their cue from one**, whereas the plural-users are responding to those [people] or the [things]. [my emphasis]

The *Chicago Manual of Style Online* does not have a specific entry that I can find. But in the text of Section 3.21, there is:

*If one or more full sentences follow it..,* thus: obviously *plural.*

There is also a question at English Language & Usage:

[Which is correct: “one or more is” or “one or more are”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13284/which-is-correct-one-or-more-is-or-one-or-more-are)

which has more than one opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong - you could argue the view that at least one item is unavailable -> is; but then you should have a singular item; if some items are unavailable, then *items* is plural. Certainly I wouldn't have used *is* here.

BTW, it would be "Today while browsing I came across this.." - present tense *come* is acceptable but gives it an informal/chatty style, not really appropriate - get is not right though.